# Word for a group or series of stories that do not relate but are published under the same name?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word that describes a collection of short stories that are published either in a single book or under the same series name. They will all have been published by the same author.

I have been operating under the pretense that the word was *non sequitur* (much like the comic) but have found that this is wrong.

I am not thinking of an *anthology*.  Similarly, *florilegium* is too complex/obscure for what I am looking for.

**Update to provide more context:** The stories may or may not have any connection to each other, but were always meant to be published together. When I think of an "anthology" I get the feeling that the stories were published a separate time and compiled later.

I am looking to ask the author some questions to see if there there is over-arching connection that I may have missed...

> Are the stories in this book *{insert word I am looking for}*, or are they actually connected?

Comment: Why aren't you thinking of anthology? Can you give an example of such a book?

Comment: A ***compilation***, a ***compendium***? It's not clear why *anthology* doesn't work, if *florilegium* would, if it weren't so  obscure, because those two words are synonymous.

Comment: _Non sequitur_ is definitely not correct: that has no connection to what you're talking about. I don't understand why you think _anthology_ would not be correct. The only other terms I can think of are _collection_ (very generic), _compilation,_ or _compendium._

Comment: @MikeHarris In the same vein as your *collection* (nice one), I suppose we could suggest ***collected works*** (not uncommon in literature), or the more general fine art terms ***opus*** or ***oeuvre***, meaning a specific artist's work(s).

Comment: @DanBron It looks like you and I are on the same page (no pun intended). Although I tend to think of _compilation_ in terms of music (a **compilation album**), I've seen it applied to written works occasionally.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I have updated the question. @DanBron

Comment: @Skooba Thanks, that does help. In the sci-fi world, we often refer to a "shared universe" or "continuity", but there may be more precise or pithier term.

Comment: @DanBron It is a Sci-fi book, and while those term would fit on the concept I was looking for something a little more "literature based" if that makes any sense...

Comment: While "anthology" is used when previously-published works are republished in a collection, I don't think it's specific to that. A book of original short stories would also be called an anthology. There are also anthology TV series like "Twilight Zone".

Comment: If there is some sense of organisation or common thread, you could use *chronicles*. An example from science fiction would be *The Majipoor chronicles*.

Comment: @PhilSweet Along the same line, ***Mythos*** and ***Cycle*** (as in Lovecraft's *[Cthulu Mythos](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cthulhu_Mythos)* and *[Dream Cycle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dream_Cycle)*, respectively, the latter being a subset of the former; a selection of related works *within* the mythos). Or, taken further, simply a ***Mythology*** (though this tends to be applied to worlds created originally from oral histories, and evolved over centuries by entire cultures, rather than individual modern writers; hence the introduction of *mythos*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After revisiting this question and the comments given. I chose to use;

[**Compendium**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/compendium)

> - 1 - A collection of concise but detailed information about a particular subject, especially in a book or other publication.
> - 1.1 -  A collection or set of similar items.

Answer (score 0):

A word that would fit in your sentence, and imply that the stores are not related, is *indepedent*.

> Are the stories in this book independent, or are they a related series?

Answer (score 0):

A Raymond Chandler collection of five books in one was called an omnibus, [https://www.amazon.com/Raymond-Chandler-Omnibus-Farewell-Lovely/dp/B001UZIJFC/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001UZIJFC). Here's another story collection called an omnibus, but by different authors [https://www.amazon.com/Great-Books-Foundation-Short-Omnibus/dp/1880323737](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1880323737).

Merriam-Webster, omnibus: "a book containing reprints of a number of works (as of a single author or on a single subject)"

The word was picked up by Ken Jennings for his podcast, https://www.omnibusproject.com, with the subtitle "An encyclopedic reference of strange-but-true stories compiled as a time capsule for future generations."

If you search for 'omnibus' at your local library, you'll see a lot of story collections.